# Sql query issue with coalesce

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, coalesce

I want to get string from three columns and I am using this query

```
String selectQuery = "select distinct coalesce(" + SENDERNAME + " , "+ SENDEREMAILID + " , " + SENDERMOBILENUMBER + ")  FROM "+ TABLE_REC ;
```

But if a perticular column has empty string it takes and shows it but if it null it is not accepting.

I want to check empty and null to not take into account. i.e. I want to show some string to the user instead of empty string.

Here are the images

***These Shows the database and query***

[image][image]

***When I fetch records and if particular record with empty and not null then it shows empty string like this***

[image][image]

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please show some examples.

Comment: @CL. I added some images for detail explanation. Please have a look on it. If you still having trouble then reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COALESCE` changes only `NULL` values, not empty strings.

To be able to use another comparison, use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SenderName <> '' THEN SenderName ELSE 'empty' END FROM TableRec
```

(The expression `SenderName <> ''` fails for both empty strings and `NULL`s.)

To combine three fields, you must nest multiple `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SenderName <> ''
            THEN SenderName
            ELSE CASE WHEN SenderEmailId <> ''
                      THEN SenderEmailId
                      ELSE SenderMobileNumber
                 END
       END
FROM TableRec
```